# Xsl Date Difference Calculation

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a requirement to calculate the difference between the current day and due day . I used the below formula and i was able to get the date difference .

```
<xsl:value-of select="(number(ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:Today())) - number(ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(string($thisNode/@DueDate))))) div 864000000000" />
```

However I now want to get only the business days in the difference (ie: Sat and Sun is not to be included. Any hints?

Comment: Where is the formula?

Comment: @robertlindgren I have a start time and end time in "Date and time" format and i want to calculate the difference between the 2 times in days,hours and minutes format in XSL. Are there any formula to calculate the number of days,hours and mins between 2 time?

Comment: May be this: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79507/xsl-date-difference-calculation

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
 =IF(AND((WEEKDAY([End Date],2))<(WEEKDAY([Start Date],2)),((WEEKDAY([Start Date],2))-(WEEKDAY([End Date],2)))>1),(((DATEDIF([Start Date],[End Date],"D")+1))-(FLOOR((DATEDIF([Start Date],[End Date],"D")+1)/7,1)*2)-2),(((DATEDIF([Start Date],[End Date],"D")+1))-(FLOOR((DATEDIF([Start Date],[End Date],"D")+1)/7,1)*2)))
```

[Reference](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/d71cb2b8-72f7-4b9f-a5c9-7c08a9ccf6c9/moss-2007networkdays-formula?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy)